# Read contents of a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

The contents of my text file are as follows:

```
a 0 45 124 234 53 12 34
a 90 294 32 545 190 87
a 180 89 63 84 73 63 83
```

How can I read the contents into a dictionary such that `a0` becomes the key and the rest of them as values. I would want my dictionary to look like this:

```
{a0: [45, 124, 234, 53, 12, 34], a90: [294, 32, 545, 190, 87], a180: [89, 63, 84, 73, 63, 83]}
```

I have tried the conventional approach where I remove the delimiter and then 
store it in the dictionary as shown below

```
newt = {}
newt = {t[0]: t[1:] for t in data}
```

But here I get only `a` as the key

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: SO ain't a code-writing service. Please show your attempts and we'll be happy to help

Comment: Can you show the code to open and read the file, without trying to do anything with the content?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because no code.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you out (it's about Christmas time after all)

```
d = {}
with open("dd.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        els = line.split()
        k = ''.join(els[:2])
        d[k] = list(map(int,els[2:]))
print(d)
```

with an input file of

```
a 0 45 124 234 53 12 34
a 90 294 32 545 190 87
a 180 89 63 84 73 63 83
```

it produces

```
{'a90': [294, 32, 545, 190, 87],
 'a180': [89, 63, 84, 73, 63, 83],
 'a0': [45, 124, 234, 53, 12, 34]}
```

It essentially reads each line from the file, it then splits it into chunks ignoring whitespace.

It then uses the first two elements to compose the key and the rest to compose a list, converting each element into an integer.

I have assumed you want the numbers as integers. If you want them as strings you can ignore the conversion to `int`

```
d[k] = els[2:]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like one-liners (kind-of):

```
with open('my_file.txt') as f:
    res = {''.join(r.split(None, 2)[:2]): [int(x) for x in r.split()[2:]] for r in f}

>>> res
{'a0': [45, 124, 234, 53, 12, 34],
 'a180': [89, 63, 84, 73, 63, 83],
 'a90': [294, 32, 545, 190, 87]}
```